# Why does pyspark contain 300MB of different jars?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

The description of the pyspark pip package https://pypi.org/project/pyspark/ says

> This Python packaged version of Spark is suitable for interacting with an existing cluster (be it Spark standalone, YARN, or Mesos) - but does not contain the tools required to set up your own standalone Spark cluster.

And if it isn't supposed to run any Spark clusters why do we have 300MB of different jars inside? It even contains kubernetes-*.jars...

About the problem I'm working on — I wanna make a minimalistic docker image for running pyspark apps in kubernetes and I'm trying to understand how pyspark works under the hood.

What my current setup is:

1. A repository with some python requirements.txt (pyspark, delta-spark, etc.)
2. An official apache spark docker image ([link](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/resource-managers/kubernetes/docker/src/main/dockerfiles/spark/bindings/python/Dockerfile#L33))
3. Once in a while i build my custom image on top of (2) adding the jars I need like delta and some /static/ python libraries that do not change often
4. Then when I push python code I build another image on top of (3) copying the py files and installing the requirements (1)

Official apache spark docker already contains all the jars, and it also contains folder python with pyspark files... So I think I do something wrong, I don't want to install pyspark from pip with all the jars it contains, but I want to install it locally, and it would be nice to have one requirements file, wouldn't it?

I can separate local requirements and /docker image/ requirements, and don't install pyspark in docker image, but is that a correct way to use pyspark?

```
requirements.common.txt (delta)
requirements.local.txt (pyspark)
requirements.docker.txt (-)
```

Install `requirements.common.txt` and `requirements.local.txt` locally, `install requirements.common.txt` and `requirements.docker.txt` when building a docker image.

Comment: Because it is a packaging and, as the doc says and most likely, it calls jar under the hood: "Using PySpark requires the Spark JARs"

Comment: 300 millibits (mb) or 300MB (megabytes)? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabyte

Comment: To be on-topic, a question needs to be about solving a specific problem you actually face. Understanding _why_ something is true, even if you'd prefer it wasn't true, doesn't constitute a practical problem with an answer that can be expected to change how you go about writing code; it's much closer to the explicitly off-topic category of a "rant in disguise".

Comment: The page that you linked to also says this: *"This packaging is currently experimental ..."* which implies to me that >they< are not entirely happy with it.  Interesting things can happen when you use experimental stuff in a way that wasn't anticipated.